# Compile Python 3.6 script to standalone exe with Nuitka on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, exe, python-3.6, nuitka

**Note:**
Before marking this question as duplicate, please verify that the other question answers the topic for this setup:

- OS: Windows 10, 64-bit
- Python version: 3.6 or higher
- Python Compiler: Nuitka, development version 0.5.30rc5
- MSVC compiler: Visual Studio 2017 Community, vcvars64.bat

### 1. How I build my exe

I'll first explain how I build my executable. Suppose I have a folder with a simple python script that I want to build:

[image]

The `buildscript.py` looks like this:

```
#####################################################
#               NUITKA BUILD SCRIPT                 #
#####################################################
# Author: Matic Kukovec
# Date: April 2018

import os
import platform


NUITKA = "C:/Python36/Scripts/nuitka3-script.py"  # Path where my nuitka3-script.py is
CWD = os.getcwd().replace("\\", "/")
MSVC = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat"
PYTHON_VERSION = "3.6"
PYTHON_EXE_PATH= "C:/Python36/python.exe"
NUMBER_OF_CORES_FOR_COMPILATION = 1 # 1 is the safest choice, but you can try more

# Generate command
command = '"{}" amd64 &'.format(MSVC)
command += "{} ".format(PYTHON_EXE_PATH)
command += "{} ".format(NUITKA)
command += "--python-version={} ".format(PYTHON_VERSION)
command += "--output-dir={}/output ".format(CWD)
command += "--verbose "
command += "--jobs={} ".format(NUMBER_OF_CORES_FOR_COMPILATION)
command += "--show-scons "
# command += "--windows-disable-console "
# command += "--icon={}/myicon.ico ".format(CWD)
command += "--standalone "
# command += "--run "
command += "{}/cubeimporter.py ".format(CWD)
os.system(command)

print("END")
```

### 2. Result of the build

After the build finishes, the folder looks like this (see picture below). As you can see, there are plenty of other files sitting next to the executable. I can see `.dll` and `.pyd` files.

[image]

### 3. Desired result

I wish I could build just a standalone executable. No dll- or other files needed. When I put the executable on a thumb drive and stick it into another computer (running Windows 10, 64-bit), it should just work. Even if there is no Python installed on that computer.

Is this possible with Nuitka?
If no, is it possible with another Python compiler?
Please provide all the steps needed, one-by-one :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easier than Nuitka for a single executable is e.g. PyInstaller:
`pyinstaller --onefile program.py` (to disable the console window for GUI applications add the `-w` option).

To create a single executable with Nuitka, you can create a SFX archive from the generated files. You can run Nuitka with the `--standalone` option which generates a `program_dist` directory.

Create then a 7-Zip SFX config file `config.txt`:

`;!@Install@!UTF-8!
GUIMode="2"
ExecuteFile="%%T/program_dist/program.exe"
;!@InstallEnd@!`

Then get the 7-Zip SFX from https://github.com/chrislake/7zsfxmm (from releases – `7zsd_extra_171_3901.7z`) and unpack the `7zsd_All_x64.sfx` file.

Pack then the `program_dist` with 7-Zip (so the folder is included in the archive) to program.7z.
Then, an SFX can be created with `copy /b 7zsd_All_x64.sfx + config.txt + program.7z single_executable.exe`.

On Unix, you can also create yourself an SFX if you create a tar archive and append it to a shell script which extract it and unpack it, for details see https://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005818.

Comment: Thank you @Fabian Heller for this post :-)

Answer (score 3):

In your `buildscript.py` file

use `--onefile` instead of `--standalone`

All the files will still be created but you don't need them and you can delete them.

Comment: Thanks @Hamza Zubair :-)

Answer (score 0):

Open console and type:

```
nuitka --recurse-all program.py
```

An exe file will be created. Run it.

Comment: That doesn't help with getting rid of the .dll and .pyd files.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, for windows

```
py -m nuitka --show-scons --show-progress --onefile --remove-output --warn-implicit-exceptions --warn-unusual-code --windows-disable-console
```

`--remove-output` takes care of removing the garbage `py -m nuitka --help`

> `--remove-output`     Removes the build directory after producing the module or exe file. Defaults to off.

If you do tkinter, insert `--enable-plugin=tk-inter`

Comment: for installer, try adding uac rights