# How to combine a exe and dependencies to one file

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, nuitka

I have a exe and some dependencies make by Nuitka.

`python -m nuitka --standalone --windows-dependency-tool=pefile --experimental=use_pefile_recurse --experimental=use_pefile_fullrecurse example.py`

How to combine them to one single file like Pyinstaller did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version [0.6.10](https://nuitka.net/posts/nuitka-release-0610.html) (Dec. 2020) or so, Nuitka has added `--onefile` option. Docs are a bit scattered/thin, but [here are some examples](https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#use-case-4-program-distribution) (also search the page for "onefile"). But basically just to add the `--onefile` argument (`--standalone` is not required).

You can also use the `-o` argument to name the final executable as something other than the name of the .py script being built (see `--help`). Not sure when that was added.

Comment: wow! awesome! thanks lot! I want it so long!
once again, thank you for tell me that!

Answer (score 0):

You could use SFX(self extracting archives) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831163/compile-python-3-6-script-to-standalone-exe-with-nuitka-on-windows-10/52837319) for a bundle exe but this works for me not in all cases.
I haven't seen a possibility to passthrough mutable user defined inputs from command line and outputs to stdout, stderr cannot be redirected.