# Nuitka: How to pack custom dist folder into a single file

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

I use *Nuitka* to compile and package my code.
Command: `python -m nuitka --onefile some_file.py`

As I understand it, Nuitka first creates a folder `some_file.dist`, where the compiled exe and all its dependencies are located, and then packs the whole folder into a single `exe` file.

Between creating the dist folder and packing it into an exe, I need to perform some manipulations with the `exe` file inside dist.

To prevent *Nuitka* from packing the dist folder into an exe, I need to use the `--standalone` argument instead of `--onefile`.
But is it possible to just pack the dist folder with *Nuitka* after my manipulations with the exe. Without compilation etc.

I tried manually creating a self-extracting archive as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831163/compile-python-3-6-script-to-standalone-exe-with-nuitka-on-windows-10/52837319), but an unpacking error appears when I run that archive. Furthermore, I haven't found a way to specify exactly where to unpack and how to get command line arguments.